# EXEC vs SP_EXECUTESQL Performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, dynamic-sql, exec, query-performance

Recently we used a sql code reviewing tool against our database. It is suggesting to use `SP_EXECUTESQL` instead of `EXEC`.

I know `SP_EXECUTESQL` helps us to avoid sql injection. Is there any difference in performance when using `EXEC` vs `SP_EXECUTESQL`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is mostly a preference due to security and consistency, and has nothing to do with performance (though that may have been more of a concern in ancient versions of SQL Server).

Why use `EXEC()` some of the time when you should be using `sp_executesql` whenever you have parameters? `EXEC()` forces you to concatenate all of your variables into a single string, and this makes it ripe for abuse.

I wrote about this in more detail here:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)

I also wrote about protecting yourself from SQL injection here:

- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

SQL injection is a pretty big deal, and plenty of [other people have written about it too](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql).

Finally, be sure when you call system procedures that you use the proper casing to match what's stored in `sys.all_objects` - it should be all lower case. Otherwise, if your code gets deployed to a case sensitive instance, it will all start failing.

Comment: It has todo with performance since every SQL which varies only in its parameters will result in a new query parsing and compile (unless simple parameterization kicks in) consuming CPU unnecessarily and filling your plan cache with garbage.

Comment: @Ochoto if you have a lot of different query texts then that will happen regardless of whether you use `EXEC('<new query text>');` or `EXEC sys.sp_executesql '<new query text>';`. To mitigate this you use `optimize for ad hoc workloads`, you don't choose between `EXEC` and `sp_executesql`.

Comment: I mean that sp_executesql admits parameterized queries and thus can reuse queries that would only differ in its parameters.

Answer (score 5):

First of all lets check what both commands mean:
`sp_executesql`: Executes a Transact-SQL statement or batch that can be reused many times, or one that has been built dynamically. The Transact-SQL statement or batch can contain embedded parameters.
`exec`: Executes a command string or character string within a Transact-SQL batch, or one of the following modules: system stored procedure, user-defined stored procedure, CLR (common language runtime) stored procedure, scalar-valued user-defined function, or extended stored procedure. The EXECUTE statement can be used to send pass-through commands to linked servers.

some of the main deferences:

1. `sp_executesql` allows for statements to be parameterized, Therefore It’s more secure than EXEC in terms of SQL injection
2. `sp_executesql` can leverage cached query plans, The TSQL string is built only one time, after that every time same query is called with `sp_executesql`, SQL Server retrieves the query plan from cache and reuses it.
3. Temp tables created in EXEC can not use temp table caching mechanism.

References:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/ 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

**Edit:**
 I found the following article regarding the performance:
The performance is a matter of debate between these two methods for stored procedures. As its name suggests, `sp_execute` is itself a stored procedure, which stores in the system database. `SP_ExecuteSQL` must require passing SQL strings to it thus, excepted to showing higher chances of caching, consequently leading to perform better when run for the second or later on times.

In other words, its parametrized dynamic T-SQL encourages its reuse. Moreover sp_execute is supposed having higher chances for avoiding unnecessary compilation while executing a dynamic query over `exec()`. 
But some experts take it as misleading as they think for both methods a plan will be cached. In fact, for the non-parametrized queries of `SP_ExecuteSQL` shows the same characteristics as the later one.

http://www.technovisitors.com/2014/07/SPExecuteSQL-Vs-Execute-SQL-Server.html

Answer (score -1):

EXEC uses the ad hoc cache and can cause ad hoc plan bloat, whereas sp_executesql doesn't, depends on how stable your plans are.

Comment: I think this may have been true in SQL Server 2000... can you demonstrate an observable difference in any modern versions?

Comment: This has not been very accurate since 2005 or so, when SQL Server added statement-level plan caches. The 'plan bloat' and re-use of such merely comes down to changes to each individual statement's text (both exec and sp_executesql inputs can contain many statements). For statements that use parameters (or if parameterization is forced) the same plan can be used if it's found in the cache. Otherwise, if the statement text changes (regardless of where it comes from) a new plan generation will be done. Both use the same underlying "ad hoc cache" mechanism, as applied to each statement.