# Why does changing parameterization style result in lower plans in the plan cache when using sp_executesql?

Tags: sql-server, plan-cache

Generally sp_execute sql will re-use cached plan, where as EXEC will create new plan for each parameter.

In this example, both queries are using sp_executesql - What is the reason that the 2nd query results in lower number of plans in the plan cache?

Query 1:

[image]
[image]

Query 2:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be a good idea to post SQL queries as text, not as images.

Comment: I presume this is a trivial example, because you can obviously change it to `WHERE ManagerID BETWEEN 1 AND 100`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has less to do with `exec` vs `sp_executesql` than your query building.

The first query actually generates 100 different queries like so,

```
select foo from bar where param=1 # Query hash abc123
select foo from bar where param=2 # Query hash def456
select foo from bar where param=3 # Query hash efg789
...
select foo from bar where param=100 # Query hash zzz999
```

These are going to end up in plan cache as you noted. The second query generates a single parametrized query like so,

```
select foo from bar where param=@p # Query hash opq789
```

So the second thing is going to run the same query with different parameter value, and the query hash stays the same. Like so,

```
select foo from bar where param=@p # Query hash opq789, @p=1
select foo from bar where param=@p # Query hash opq789, @p=2
select foo from bar where param=@p # Query hash opq789, @p=3
...
select foo from bar where param=@p # Query hash opq789, @p=100
```

As a rule of a thumb, [don't use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165186/4511) `exec` unless you must. It's prone to SQL injections.

Edit: As per why you are getting multiple plans. SQL Server calculates a hash of the query, which it will use to look up if the same query has already been submitted and if there's re-usable plan(s) in the plan cache.

When the queries use hard-coded values, such as `param=1`, `param=2` etc, each query will get a different hash (barring collisions, but that's not relevant here). Different hash means that SQL Server thinks it hasn't seen the query before, so it creates and caches it (barring optimize for ad hoc workloads setting, in which only plan stub is cached for the first execution). There is forced parametrization, that can be used to, well, force the parameters to be parameters instead of hard-coded values.

When the queries use parameters, such as `param=@value`, the query hash does not include whatever value will be passed in `@value`. Thus whenever the same query is re-run with different value for the parameter, it is going to use the same plan (unless Query Optimizer notices that the plan isn't any good anymore or plan cache is purged.)

Comment: So with respect to plan cache, query 1 is the same as EXEC?

Comment: @variable Apples and oranges. If your _queries are different_, that is the issue, not if you `exec` or not.

Comment: I am asking because exec always results in new plan for each parameter.

Comment: As already noted, your first batch does not use parameterization at all. That's just simple dynamic sql. YOU might think of that as "using parameters" but those are 100 different (however slightly) queries to the database engine. Try using EXEC with the same exact statement 100 times.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example you are not really using the parameterization capabilities of sp_executesql as you are building a new string each time & any change in the query string will result in a new plan.

In the second example the query string stays constant and you pass an outer parameter through sp_executesql to the inner parameter as defined within the query string.

As you have shown the 2nd method is generally more efficient

Comment: So the 1st method is equivalent of using EXEC?

Comment: effectively yes